# How to get maximum time of a particular id and group by id in C#

Tags: c#, lambda, group-by

I have the following code, this is a sample code, just need to create sample list to show client data.

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        List<Author> authors = new List<Author>
        {
            new Author { Id = "100", Status = "A", Value = "100", dateTime = dt1.AddMinutes(-5) },
            new Author { Id = "101", Status = "A", Value = "100", dateTime = dt1.AddMinutes(-8)  },
            new Author { Id = "100", Status = "A", Value = "200", dateTime = dt1.AddMinutes(-6)  },
            new Author { Id = "100", Status = "A", Value = "250" , dateTime = dt1.AddMinutes(-18)},
            new Author { Id = "101", Status = "A", Value = "600" , dateTime = dt1.AddMinutes(-6)},
            new Author { Id = "100", Status = "A", Value = "700" , dateTime = dt1.AddMinutes(-3)}
        };

        var aa = authors.ToList();
    }
}

public class Author
{
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public string Status { get; set; }
    public string Value { get; set; }
    public dateTime dateTime { get; set; }
}
```

I need to get distinct Id with their maximum dateTime value.

According to my expectation, output should be these two list values:

```
new Author { Id = "100", Status = "A", Value = "700" , dateTime = dt1.AddMinutes(-3)}
new Author { Id = "101", Status = "A", Value = "600" , dateTime = dt1.AddMinutes(-6)}
```

Answer (score 1):

using LINQ it looks like:

```
var r = authors.GroupBy(a => a.Id).Select(g =>
  new { Id = g.Key, MaxDate = g.Max(a => a.dateTime) }
);
```

If you exactly want Author objects out, it's:

```
var r = authors.GroupBy(a => a.Id).Select(g =>
  g.OrderByDescending(a => a.dateTime).First()
);
```

In the above, everything I've aliased as `a` is an Author object, and `g` is an IGrouping - in this case a list of authors that all share the same id.

GroupBy essentially returns a list of lists of authors. The outer list has a Key which is what everything in the inner list shares, in this case the same author id. This means the select pulls the shared key and then does a max on all the author objects that share that key looking for the highest dateTime for each key

If you know sql grouping the main thing to get your head around with LINQ grouping is that unlike sql, LINQ doesn't necessarily throw any info away, it just divides the data up into groups under shared properties but you still have all the data that went into it. In contrast an sql grouping goes the next step of performing the aggregating too and only giving you the results of the grouping op - with sql you have to specify some aggregation, with linq you don't

Comment: what is g? can u please look on that sir

Comment: compile erorr, : The name 'g' does not exist in the current context

Comment: g is the IGrouping produced by the GroupBy operation. Check that your select has `g =>`

Comment: Sir I have this 'public IList<T> rows { get; set; }'. I need assign above query result into this. once I trying to do that, I'm getting ,`Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.List<<anonymous type: string Id, string Status>>' to 'System.Collections.Generic.IList<T>'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)`

Comment: And what is T? An Author? If so, you need to call ToList() on r, but the second query I posted that returns Authors, not the first one that returns the id/time pair. Your question wasn't particularly clear what the output was to be, and didn't make any mention of how you were going to use it

Answer (score 1):

you can do it as shown below:

Although you can do it in a simpler way, it's just for a better understanding

```
        var temp = authors.GroupBy(t => t.Id)
                          .Select(t => new Author { Id=t.Key, dateTime = t.Max(f =>f.dateTime) }).ToList();

//Select by LINQ query
        var query = from n in authors
                    join t in temp on new { n.Id, n.dateTime } equals new { t.Id, t.dateTime }
                    select n;
```

Comment: Generally on SO we have a rule that we don't post answers that are essentially a repeat of an earlier posted answer, especially when they are just a block of code with zero explanation